# Powerbi - view the query used to pull in data

Tags: sql, powerbi

I've downloaded the pbix of a report from a colleague. I'd like to view the SQL query that was used to pull the data into this report. When clicking on 'edit queries' I can see the output of the query, but not the query itself. How do I view the query itself? Note I would like to see the query before any steps Power BI takes. I found something in 'advanced editor' that looks code-like but it doesn't seem to be the raw original code.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the table/query on the left pane. On the right side you see the steps he applied in the query designer and under `Home > Advanced Editor` you see the whole code what happended.